# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in VSCODE

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I ran the code `import requests` in my file and this error come out `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Things I have tried:

1. installed requests in both windows terminal and vscode terminal
   that gives the output `Requirement already satisfied`
2. ran `pip freeze` requests==2.25.1 is registered
3. tried `./pip freeze` on the terminal to check if i'm on the wrong terminal as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58160615/15232456 suggests and error: The term './pip' is not recognized
4. Tried adding the workspace settings path in vscode

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${c:/dev/ala/venv/Scripts/python.exe}/code/venv/bin/python"
}
```

Perhaps something wrong in this implementation?

Edit: "python.pythonPath" has been replaced by "defaultInterpreterPath"?

so I tried this instead:

```
{
    "defaultInterpreterPath": "${c:/python36/python.exe}/code/venv/bin/python"
}
```

Need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing requests with:

`python3 -m pip install requests`
or

`python -m pip install requests`
or

`py -m pip install requests`?

Comment: Yes I have, I run that both on windows terminal and Vscode,
and this is the output:
‎‎‎
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.25.1)
‎‎
there were other lines as well that says pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Do not post comments as answers.