# Why can't I import requests in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I want to use request module, but whenever I tried to import requests I got this message:

```
import "requests" could not be resolved from source Pylance
```

I already used pip to install the requests module, but I still receive this error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' using venv in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160360/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-using-venv-in-vscode)

Comment: `use request module in vs code` that will not work because VSC is JavaScript (Node.js) based. VSC is the editor with which you create Python scripts that use `requests`

Comment: don't add quotes, read the python doc on `import`

Comment: @rioV8 It doesn't matter what Vscode is written in. Sounds like you've not used the Python extension. The quotes are part of the error in the pylance parser, not the actual code

Comment: in which python interpreter (virtual environment) have you installed it and which interpreter is used for running the script. Try to find the module in the File Explorer of your OS to be sure it is in the correct place

Comment: Did you use any virtual environment? Can you run `pip show requests` in integrated Terminal to check if its location is in `your current selected interpreter\lib\site-package`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832892/why-cant-i-import-requests-in-vs-code

Answer (score 78):

Have you made sure that you have installed the module by running

```
pip install requests
```

or

```
pip3 install requests
```

Additionally, you can tell VS Code to use different Python-interpreter in your system. I e.g. had the same problem, that VS Code code check gave me the warning, that I don't have the module requests installed, but when I run the python script it worked anyhow. That's why I believe that the python code check in VS Code can use different Python versions and related python packages than your system use when you run the code.

What helped me in order to get rid of the VS Code error message, choosing a different Python from here:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code IDE. Change Python version for code check]

Comment: Changing Python version in VS Code solved it for me

Comment: Don't forget to restart the VS Code after changing the Python version.

Comment: A restart, or a simply "reload window" too

Comment: It works without restarting anything now

Comment: If you are using virtual environments, ensure that the selected Python Path refers to your virtual environment. VS Code does not switch per default to the "correct" Python path, even when you call `code .`  from within the virtual environment.

Answer (score 25):

I got the same error and solved it with this:

```
import pip._vendor.requests
```

Comment: Welcome and good suggestion! If you could explain why this works, or confirm that this is equivalent to the regular import, then that would help improve the experience for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: This resolves my issue as well, but still we need to understand why we need to import like this. As in my previous VS code installation I can directly use normal import and it worked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, as it works. But can you pease explain why?

Comment: For the ones wondering why this needed - it's because VSCode is not completely sure that it's a python. So, you have to explicitly clarify the library - just like you'd do for any reference in any language. But if you explicitly use a `.py` extension for this file, you wouldn't need that.

Answer (score 9):

If you are experiencing this problem on Windows, look at the installed extensions. I had this problem on both of my Windows machines. I noted that I had two extensions installed: Pylance & Intellisense (Pylance).
Uninstalling Pylance and keeping intellisense (Pylance) solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was that the Python interpreter being used was the default one instead on the virtual environment one. I had activated my venv and installed the requests package, but still was getting the error message. So I checked on the bottom right and noticed the default "global" interpreter was selected:

[image: Python version]

All I had to do was switch to the interpreter in my virtual environment (it even shows up as "Recommended"):
[image: Recommended interpreter]

and it automatically started recognizing the package (no VSCode restart needed or anything).

Answer (score 3):

I had this - and noticed that my workspace wasn't trusted.

This doesn't allow the pylance extension to check what modules are installed.  Setting the workspace to trusted (bottom left on the status bar where it says restricted) allowed pylance to check for installed modules.

Failing this, other answers may apply.

Comment: My Workspace is trusted but still getting that error

Comment: @Umang As mentioned in the answer - other answers may apply.

Comment: This one solved it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try choosing the python interpreter manually. Choose view - select interpreter - enter interpreter path - choose the python folder - [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkHPs.png) then python application. This should work

Comment: This is not an answer. You should validate the answer that worked for you, and if needed give clarification in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You command line interface has to be in the venv to install the "requests" API.
[image]

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

From VS code terminal `set venv - C:\Python310\python.exe  -m venv 'PATH_TO_VENV\.venv\'`

After this verify packages are available

```
pip list
```

if required:

```
pip install requests
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with importing `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` packages.
When I tried to install them by `pip install requests` and `pip install beautifulsoup4` I got the message that said "Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.9.3)".
So the way I solved this issue was by directly installing these packages to the version of Python I am currently using.

```
pip3.10.exe install requests
pip3.10.exe install beautifulsoup4
```

You can replace the part "3.10.exe" with your current version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I too got same error and it got resolved by giving url in ""(double quotes). [image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Switching the interpreter in the VS code solved my problem. Went from 3.11.1 to 3.7 base - Conda.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33765268)

Answer (score 1):

It works after I switch the Python version. See the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCODE with a python virtual environment.
use `ctrl+shift+p` or `cmd+shift+p` to open the command palette.

Type `python intepreter` in the command palette and select it.

The new environment can be found here, it will have a new prefixed with your project folder name.

If you don't find any similar names, try refreshing the [python interpreters list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0lpF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you explicitly set a file extension to `.py`. But the answer by @Murat Büyükaksu works just fine with extension or w/out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I first had to upgraded pip by going to python 3 installable folder and running the command visual studio code was suggesting along with error when I first try to install requests package and then was able to run the following in command palette.

pip install requests

After installation, restart the code and after that code doesn't complain.
my python version - 3.10.5

Answer (score 0):

Update version to 3.11.

[1 - Click on version number in above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR3JZ.jpg)

[2 - Choice python version 3.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkJYn.jpg)

[3 - The problem solves here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F89vS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue in Ubuntu using the following method:

Go to the left bottom and select the interpreter as indicated below.

[image]

[image]

After choosing 'workspace', the second option, the issue was completely resolved.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to change the interpreter. I solved this conflict by going to 3.8.8 (conda) from 3.9.9 (windows).

Answer (score -1):

1. Open interpreters
2. Try all of them one by one

The problem is you might have installed the module in one env and not in the other one, so either install in each or try each of them!

Click on bottom-left:

[image]